# Exceptions in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

The file 'mig.txt' does not exist in my current working directory. So the following code should encounter an IOError exception and since 'mig.txt' was never created, it should also raise a 'NameError' indicating that 'bat' is not defined. But how come the finally block works fine even if the file was never created? Is it something related to the Python version (3.6.0)?

```
try:
    bat=open('mig.txt')
    print(bat.readline(),end='')
except IOError:
    print('File error')
finally:
    bat.close()
```

Output:

```
File error
```

Comment: What do you mean? You carefully check if that name exists *before* trying to access its attributes. Why would you expect a name error?

Comment: Apology. I just had to edit the finally block by removing 'if 'bat' in locals:'. I still get the same output.

Comment: I expect a name error because the file mig.txt was never created and hence, it is impossible to call the close() method on it right?

Comment: Without that test I *do* get a name error when running your code, using 3.6.0.

Comment: The correct behaviour of Python 3.6 is to output 'File error', then report the NameError. It works fine on my machine. Maybe there is something wrong with your Python configuration? Python 3 writes the NameError to stderr, not stdout...

Answer (score 0):

In the code that you posted, you **will** get a `NameError`, as well as as the output `File error` when you run it in python 3.6.  The reason this happens is the `finally` block is always executed, no matter what happens in the `try/catch` block (unless you exit the program).